# Standard deviation formula for multiple binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

I want to combine more than 20 different binomial distributions and then I would like to find their combined standard deviation.

For the time being, let us assume that there are only $3$ different binomial distributions with the following parameters:

First: 
$n = 1000$; $p = 2.5$%

Second:
$n = 400$; $p = 6$%

Third:
$n = 200$; $p = 3$%

I want to combine those $3$ into one case, how do I find the standard deviation of the combined case?

I do know the simple formula for just one binomial distribution is this:

$$\sqrt{n p (1-p)}$$

Comment: How are you combining them: as a mixture or as a sum or something else?  You may find it easier to look for $E\left[X_i\right]$ and $Var(X_i)$ and $E\left[X_i^2\right]$ for each, then  $E\left[Y\right]$ and $E\left[Y^2\right]$ for the combination whatever it is and thus $Var(Y)$ and the standard deviation

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Do you mean convolution? This question is not well specified.

Comment: Like a sum. by combine I mean like, let's say I get a gold for that chances (2.5%, 6%, 3%), then I'm summing up all the gold that I got from them.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$ @Henry?

Comment: $E[Y]$ is the expected value of your combination (the mean or first moment) and $E[Y^2]$ is the expected value of the square of your combination (the second raw moment but not the square of the expected value).  For an ordinary binomial distribution they are both $np$ ; for a normal distribution they are $\mu$ and $\mu^2+\sigma^2$

Comment: I see..., I think I get what to do now, thanks for the help

Comment: That was an error: the second raw moment of a binomial distribution is $n^2p^2+np - np^2$

Comment: I got minus...
$\tag*{}$
$E[Y]$ = 1000*2.5% + 400*6% + 200*3% = 55 $\tag*{}$
$E[Y^2]$ = 1000^2*(2.5%)^2 + 1000*(2.5%) - 1000*(2.5%)^2 + 400^2*(6%)^2 + 400*(6%) - 400*(6%)^2 + 200^2*(3%)^2 + 200*(3%) - 200*(3%)^2 = 1290 $\tag*{}$
$Var[Y]$ = $E[Y^2]−E[Y]^2$ $\tag*{}$
= 1290 - 3025 = -1,735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and it's actually very simple just
$$\sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^k {n_i p_i ( 1 - p_i )}}$$

so the standard deviation of that three combined case above is
$\sqrt {(1000 \times 2.5\% ( 1 - 2.5\% )) + (400 \times 6\% ( 1 - 6\% )) + (200 \times 3\% ( 1 - 3\% ))}$

$= 7.263263729$